# How to check for win in custom sized tic-tac-toe diagonals

Tags: python, list, logic, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game, where user can specify the size of the grid (amount of columns and rows).
I need to create a function, that could check for a win in all the diagonals in the grid.

For the grid, I'm using a 2-dimensional list, that looks like this (3x3 example):

```py
grid = [['x', '-', 'o'], 
        ['o', 'x', '-'], 
        ['-', '-', 'x']]
grid[row][col]
```

This should be a winning situation

I have already created a check for the vertical and horizontal win, but I can't quite figure out, how to check for the diagonals.

Here is how I check for row win in my code:

`min_win_streak` is the minimum winning streak (for example in classical 3x3 tic-tac-toe, it would be 3)

```py
def check_rows(grid, min_win_streak):
    winner = '-'
    for row in grid:
        win_streak = 0
        for element in row:
            if element != '-':
                if element == winner:
                    win_streak += 1
                    winner = element
                    if win_streak >= min_win_streak:
                        return True, winner
                else:
                    win_streak = 1
                    winner = element
            else:
                win_streak = 0
                winner = '-'
    return False, None
```

I need the `check_diags()` function, the returns should be:

- **win for x**, the function should **return True, 'x'**
- **win for o**, the function should **return True, 'x'**
- **no win**, the function should **return False, None**

Comment: Please provide your existing code for one of the directions, so that we can adapt that to your needs.  Asking us to provide the code from scratch is a bit out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Even more, it wouldn't merge nicely with what you've already done.

Comment: @Prune I've added the check_rows() function

Comment: Have you tried using nested for loops and a mathematical formula, something like 'if grid[i][j] == grid[i+1][j+1] == grid[i+2][j+2]'? You'd need to make sure i and j are in range(len(grid)-2).

Comment: @ToddBurus I have tried, but I wan't able to figure out any kind of formula for it.

Comment: Well, any diagonals will all be of a form (i, j), (i+1, j+1), (i+2, j+2) (i.e. a downward sloping diagonal) or (i, j+2), (i+1, j+1), (i+2, j) (an upward sloping diagonal). Then you could put that in a nested for loop clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for diagonals in a 2x2 using the following nested for loops:

```
for i in range(len(grid)-2):
    for j in range(len(grid)-2):
        if grid[i][j] == grid[i+1][j+1] == grid[i+2][j+2] and grid[i][j] != '-':
            print('Winner')
        elif grid[i][j+2] == grid[i+1][j+1] == grid[i+2][j] and grid[i][j+2] != '-':
            print('Winner')
```

Insert this into a function with the desired returns in place of the print statements if you desire. This should be extendable to 3x3, 4x4, etc. with fairly easy alterations.

Comment: Normally, this code would work, but the problem is, that user can specify the size of the grid, and that can be something like 5x8, not only NxN, and this code fails in those situations, and user can also specify how big the win streak can be, (in this case it is 3), but this can change.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread his intentions. I took "win streak" to mean something else without reading through the added code. And I assumed the grid was square. It would be easy enough to modify with some added variables to account for those factors. A diagonal is a diagonal. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your code.  I replaced your win_streak check loop with the `all` function.  The code below does more work than you'd want to use for a huge grid, but it's easy (easier) to understand and adapt, and it's fast enough to use for a game of go-moku (5 in a row on a 19x19 board).

I left in one tracing `print` statement to illustrate the diagonals it's checking.  You should be able to adapt this to the NE-SW diagonals (`check_slash_diag`).

```
grid = [['x', '-', 'o', 'o'],
        ['o', 'x', 'o', '-'],
        ['-', 'o', 'x', 'x'],
        ['-', 'x', 'o', '-']]

def check_backslash_diag(grid, min_win_streak):

    grid_size = len(grid)
    grid_extra = grid_size - min_win_streak   # This is the "extra" space in a long line

    # This pair of loops will iterate through the upper-left square of side 
    #   grid_extra+1, starting points of any diagonals long enough to contain a win.
    for start_row in range(grid_extra+1):
        for start_col in range(grid_extra+1):
            # Extract a diagonal "row" of length min_win_streak
            diag = [grid[start_row+i][start_col+i] for i in range(min_win_streak)]
            print(start_row, start_col, diag)  # DEBUG: Display checked diagonals
            if all(diag[i] == diag[0] for i in range(min_win_streak)):
                print(diag[0], "wins on NW-SE diagonal at", start_row, start_col)

check_backslash_diag(grid, 3)
```

Output:

```
0 0 ['x', 'x', 'x']
x wins on NW-SE diagonal at 0 0
0 1 ['-', 'o', 'x']
1 0 ['o', 'o', 'o']
o wins on NW-SE diagonal at 1 0
1 1 ['x', 'x', '-']
```